# Postgres optimize several left joins on one table

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization

I have a postgres schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE rows
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  start_year integer
);

CREATE TABLE calculations
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  row_id bigint NOT NULL,
  year integer,
  calculation numeric(23,7)
);

INSERT INTO rows (id, start_year)
VALUES
  (1, 2020),
  (2, 2021);
  
INSERT INTO calculations (id, row_id, year, calculation)
VALUES
  (1, 1, 2019, 0),
  (2, 1, 2020, 100),
  (3, 1, 2021, 900),
  (4, 1, 2022, 300),
  (5, 1, 2023, 500),
  (6, 2, 2019, 220),
  (7, 2, 2020, 111),
  (8, 2, 2021, 222),
  (9, 2, 2024, 333),
  (10, 2, 2025, 444);
```

A an SQL view with select like this:

```
SELECT
  row.id,
  calc1.calculation as calc1,
  calc2.calculation as calc2,
  calc3.calculation as calc3
FROM
  rows row
  LEFT JOIN calculations calc1 on calc1.row_id = row.id and calc1.year = row.start_year
  LEFT JOIN calculations calc2 on calc2.row_id = row.id and calc2.year = row.start_year + 1
  LEFT JOIN calculations calc3 on calc3.row_id = row.id and calc3.year = row.start_year + 2;
```

Actually both tables are way larger. SQL query takes about 10 sec to execute and most of it is taken by calculations. The only thing I've managed to optimize it so far is:

```
SELECT
  row.id,
  calc.calculation->(row.start_year)::text as calc1,
  calc.calculation->(row.start_year+1)::text as calc2,
  calc.calculation->(row.start_year+2)::text as calc3
FROM
  rows row
  LEFT JOIN (select row_id, json_object_agg(year, calculation) as calculation
                    from calculations
                    group by row_id) calc on calc.row_id = row.id
```

Now it has x2 performance boost, but it not enough. It queries unneeded year values. When I've replaced this query with taking first, second and third year, it was working much faster., so I wonder if there is another way to merge these JOINs to one with performance boost.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8ff004/4

Answer (score 3):

You may try adding the following index to the `calculations` table:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_calc ON calculations (row_id, year, calculation);
```

This index, if used, has the ability to speed up the multiple joins to the `calculations` table.

Comment: A good idea, I've forgot that indexes could be complex. Seems like I need to invent it in some of my tables. In my particular case index on (row_id, year) given me a boost, but, unfortunatelly, SELECT with JSON still works slightly faster.